# Android broadcast boot completed not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I have a problem with the BROADCAST receiver in Android.
All receivers work well but not working RECEIVED_BOOT_COMPLETED.
Some idea?

**MANIFIEST FILE:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<receiver
android:name="telint.sms.appClass.SMSReceiver"
android:enabled="true" >
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**CODE:**

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String ACTION_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String ACTION_BOOT = "android.provider.Telephony.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED";
private static final String ACTION_INTERNET = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";
private static final String ACTION_SHUTDOWN = "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN";
     @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_BOOT)){
        **//NOT WORKING HERE.**
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your action name is wrong.

Just replace

```
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

By

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

And also

```
private static final String ACTION_BOOT = "android.provider.Telephony.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED";
```

By

```
private static final String ACTION_BOOT = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
```

Answer (score 1):

To get boot completed one needs to add 2 things to AndroidManifest file:

- Inside broadcast "receiver"s "intent filter"

  < action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/ >
- Also get permission

  < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />